# Rotate the text inside <td>, but doesn't allow to increase the width of <td>?

Tags: html, css, html-table, rotation

I have a table with the fixed-widths and I am trying to rotate the text inside one `<td>` without affecting the layout of table. But the problem is if the text is big, it wraps the text. I tried to set `nowrap` but it is not working with `%`, however, its working with `px`.

```css
table {
  border:1px solid black;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}

table td {
  border:1px solid black;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}

.vertical-align{
 transform:rotate(-90deg); 
 white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td style="width:5%;" rowspan="2" class="vertical-align" >
    Dummy Heading   Dummy Heading
  </td>
    <td style="width:95%;">
    Dummy Text Dummy Text
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>

    <td style="width:95%;">
    Dummy Text Dummy Text
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zyLueco1/2/).

I don't want to increase the size of td, doesn't matter how big the text. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

`<td class="vertical-align">text</td>`

Like this:

`<td><span class="vertical-align">text</span></td>`

I added span in td because I want to add `writing-mode: vertical-rl` style for text and td element does not support this properly. An example below:

```css
table {
  border-collapse:collapse
}

table td {
  border:1px solid black
}

.vertical-align {
  white-space:nowrap;
  -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  -ms-writing-mode: tb-rl;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  padding: 10%; /* optional */
  transform: rotate(180deg) /* you want */
}
```

```html
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td width="5%" rowspan="2"><span class="vertical-align">Dummy Heading Dummy Heading</span></td>
    <td width="95%">Dummy Text Dummy Text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="95%">Dummy Text Dummy Text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't care if my text comes out of the td. I don't want to increase the size of my firs td.

Comment: This is what I was looking for.